# Sort the date when using group by, where the display format of the date is user defined

Tags: sql, oracle

In the below query,

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(hiredate,'MON-YYYY') Year_of_Hiring, COUNT(empno) No_of_Joinees 
FROM emp
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hiredate,'MON-YYYY');
```

How should I mention the format in ORDER BY clause, if I want to sort the result by hiredate.

Comment: @forpas That would order alpha-numerically by the formatted string and not chronologically.

Comment: @MT0 you are right. I read only the *How should I mention the format..* part of the question.

Comment: Why is a group by `MON-YYYY` named **Year**_of_Hiring in the output? That doesn't make a lot of sense, does it? Isn't it rather **Month**_of_Hiring?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aggregation function to order by the original date:

```
order by min(hiredate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by and order by `TRUNC(hiredate, 'MM')` and then format it in the `SELECT` clause:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(hiredate, 'MM'),'MON-YYYY') AS Year_of_Hiring,
       COUNT(empno) No_of_Joinees 
FROM   emp
GROUP BY TRUNC(hiredate, 'MM')
ORDER BY TRUNC(hiredate, 'MM');
```

Comment: This is generally much better than grouping by the string representation of (truncated) dates. One thing to keep in mind, though: even though Oracle "learned" to use hashing for aggregation (instead of the older and slower "sort group by"), if the query then also orders by the same columns as it aggregates by, it will default back to "sort group by" - which doesn't make a lot of sense if the input is millions of rows but the output (and therefore the `ORDER BY`) is (applies to) just eight or sixty rows. That can be fixed with a hint, `use_hash_aggregation`.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the explanation.